# How to Censor a SPECIFIC word in Java using Regex

Tags: java, regex, profanity

I'd like to know how to censor the word "ass" (or A word) using a Java Regex highly safe.

This makes things difficult as the A word can be contained in a lot of other harmless words. For example, "grass."

I have setup partially the beginning part for a lot of the prefixes of the A word, but can't seem to find how to censor the word without censoring suffixes like "assassin."

```
String string = String.replaceAll("^(?!(b|B|gr|gR|Gr|GR|gl|gL|Gl|GL|m|M|s|S|h|H|p|P|g|G)).*[aA4]+[\\W[_]]*?[$5SszZ]+[\\W[_]]*?[$5SszZ]+", "***");
```

This I find is very hard, and still can not find a solution yet.

Comment: "The A word"? This is a [known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem) problem. You could censor it only when it's the entire word. You have another problem, though: Your naughty word has another [perfectly innocent meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donkey).

Comment: This is certainly a clbuttic issue.

Answer (score 2):

**USING LOOKAROUNDS**

```
(?<=\s)(?:ass)(?=\s)
```

will check for spaces or linebreaks around the word.
If you want the word to be censored even when surrounded by non-letter characters (`:ass:`), use this:

```
(?<=\W)(?:ass)(?=\W)
```

If you're looking for case-insensitive search, add `(?i)` at the beggining.

**USING WORDS BOUNDARIES**

Someone in the comments suggested a better way :

```
\b(?:ass)\b
```

Or for special characters:

```
\b([&#"'-_$^])?(?:ass)([&#"'-_$^])?\b
```

Comment: Why not just use a [boundary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html) for words, which is `\b`?

Comment: That is indeed a better solution. I'm not used to using `\b`. Would it just simply replace both lookarounds?

Comment: Yeah, just as with the example in the docs I linked, you just do `\bword\b` to look for that word. So in their example, `\bdog\b` will find `dog` in a sentence, but will skip `doggie`.

Comment: So, this will detect and remove the word if there is nothing after the actual word?

Comment: If you use it in a replaceAll, yes. If there is nothing surrounding the actual word. The second regex will also check for special characters, the third one won't.

Comment: @Docteur The solution #1 and #2 don't censor the word by itself, solution #3 creates another problem; people may put something in front of it to bypass it. EDIT: For solution #3, some people might put other special characters between letters. "a %$^%$#@ s %$&^ s" for example.

Comment: What do you mean? You need to use substitution (replaceAll). The first two matches the word, what's the issue? As I've stated, the third one does not take special characters into account.

Comment: @Agentleader1 Added a fourth one using the `\b` components but taking special characters into account.